# Como renderizar um arquivo em um frame?

Tags: javascript, pdf, impressão

Eu consumo um serviço que retorna um arquivo em PDF, eu tenho uma aplicação web que Atualmente eu do um Windows open na chamada do serviço e faz download do arquivo.

Porém eu preciso agora renderizar esse arquivo para poder gerar a impressão automática dele.

Alguém sabe como posso renderizar esse arquivo por uma requisição Ajax ou frame? Para poder tentar de alguma forma imprimir?

meu código é window.open(url)

Comment: Seja bem-vinda, poderia [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/268915/edit) sua pergunta e colocar o código que já tentou fazer ? Ou um [MCVE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Aproveite também e faça o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender mais sobre a **comunidade**.

Comment: Nem sempre o browser vai permitir que você mostre o pdf embutido na página.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar um renderizador de PDF totalmente escrito em HTML5/JavaScript (não usa bibliotecas ou frameworks externos) e compatível com todos os navegadores modernos chamado **[pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)**. Além de exibir o PDF na página, ele possui muitas funcionalidades (inclusive de imprimir).

Você pode baixar o pacote direto na página do componente: http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

- GitHub: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js
- Demo online: http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

Ao subir os arquivos do componente para o servidor, existe um arquivo chamado `viewer.html` dentro da pasta `web` que renderiza o PDF. Você pode chamar esse arquivo via `window.open` enviando na URL o parâmetro `?file` com o nome do PDF que você quer abrir. Exemplo:

```
window.open('viewer.html?file=ARQUIVO_PDF.pdf','_blank','width=1000, height=500');
```